# How do I spy on methods called from one class that exist in another class using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a method

```
thisSvc.asyncOperation: function(id) {
   return thatSvc.getById(id);
```

Is it possible to create a spy that will tell me if thatSvc.getById has been called, or is this design an anti-pattern? AFAIK, spies can only be created on a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spy on whatever you want, in your jasmine tests just make sure you get that service:

```
var thisSvc, thatSvc;

beforeEach(inject(function(_thisSvc_, _thatSvc_){
    thisSvc = _thisSvc_;
    thatSvc = _thatSvc_;
});

it('.asyncOperation should call thatSvc.getById', function(){
    spyOn(thatSvc, 'getById');
    var id = 4;

    thisSvc.asyncOperation(id);

    expect(thatSvc.getById).toHaveBeenCalledWith(id);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/spy-on-javascript-methods-using-the-jasmine-testing-framework.html#fbid=ib4OX6qA3oS

"spyOn() can only be used when the method already exists on the object. For simple tests, this is your best bet."

Comment: Depending on how your code is structured, you could easily create a mock object for `thatSvc` and inject it into your SUT.